# Хранение и быстрый доступ к большому объему данных

Tags: sql, производительность, база-данных

Имеется выделенные сервер, он служит сервером-обработчиком некоторой программы-клиента. Он хранит, сравнительно редко(с запросами получения) обновляемые данные(раз в 5-10 минут не большими пачками), притом на данный момент идет около 50 селектов в секунду, кол-во постепенно растет. Сейчас используется mysql база данных. Что посоветуете для подобных операция, селекты примитивные, объем данных большой.

Comment: не совсем понял из вопроса на "выделенном сервере" у вас есть серверная часть приложения или только субд ? + было бы неплохо увидеть структуру таблиц в которых "объем данных большой" + их размер

Comment: есть не большое серверное приложение, которое хватает данные с внешних источников и добавляет их в бд, оно же отдает результат при запросе, уже приложения-клиента.
Стркуттура:

имя(уникальное(varchar 15)) | кол-во запросов по данному имени(int) | | статус(1 или 0)
На данный момент таких записей около 500т

Comment: Mysql - сжечь, старая технология для таких нагрузок, используйте PostgreSQL.

Comment: вы видимо сложнее 2х табличного сайтика никогда ничего не писали, хотел бы я посмотреть как вы будете переписывать архитектуру приложения с нуля под новую СУБД, или вы надеетесь что старые запросы на новой субд будут все так же эффективно работать?

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, мне вот интересно, обосновать-то вы это сможете без гугла? (Для красоты эксперимента представим, что я гопник и говорю это соответствующим голосом)

Comment: @avengerweb, если я правильно посчитал, то у Вас около **10 мегабайт** сырых данных.

Неужели это большой объем?

Comment: почему никто не написал, что все сильно зависит от того, какой селект именно делается, есть ли индексы. 50 селектов в секунду и SQLite сделает ненапрягаясь, если все правильно настроить.

Comment: Кол-во запросов и данных с каждым днем растет, в данный момент все вполне не плохо работает на mysql, но это пока, я хочу подготовится к тому моменту когда всего будет уже много и должно будет работать быстро, да пока нагрузка не особо большая. + планируется доработка системы, которая добавит еще несколько данных в таблицу, может в другую, но это не имеет значения.

Comment: Для начала спланируйте размещение журнальных файлов СУБД на отдельном **быстром** (15k rpm) диске (можно в мирроринге).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

есть несколько методов которые применимы практически в любых ситуациях:

1) кеширование данных
2) разделение данных на более мелкие части которые удобнее выбирать (и как результат кешировать)
3) разделение динамичных и статичных данных (т.е. отделить данные которые обновляются часто от тех которые обновляются редко)
4) на стороне субд часто используемые данные можно хранить сразу в памяти
5) физическое разделение данных (разные индексы, партиции)

з.ы. если возникает проблема частого использования одной таблицы зачастую это означает что что-то неверно спроэктировано

Answer (score 2):

Если хотите долго и счастливо жить с одной СУБД - берите что-нибудь из большой тройки: Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server или IBM DB/2 - не прогадаете. Будете только менять/наращивать железо и все.

Если вы бедны и несчастны - постарайтесь прожить с MySQL с движком InnoDB (про движок MyISAM забудьте). А менять MySQL на Postgres это все равно что шило на мыло.

Постарайтесь хорошо вложиться в железо: 64-х разрядное промжелезо с нормальной оперативкой + RAID массивы - можно довольно долго прожить - ну по крайней мере до 64 терабайт ))